# How to get a 0mq server to process 2 messages simultaneously

Tags: python, asynchronous, zeromq

I want to send 2 messages to a 0mq server and have them process simultaneously. Right now when I send my server a message it process the message, but is unable to accept another message till it is done with the first.

So I have to wait until the first message is done until I can send the 2nd or else it will just ignore it.

I need to be able to process the 2nd while the 1st one is processing because I am trying to send a "pause" message to the server to stop processing message 1 until I say say to start again.

Any help would be appreciated. I have tried multiple ways of getting it to be async but it is not working. Tried using ChatGPT and it just ran me in circles.

using Router/Dealer atm

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved is using 0mq PUSH/PULL.

I put the incoming messages in a queue.

To get the pause to work, I put my function to sleep for a short amount of time so other message in the queue could get worked on. So my pause function was able to change a class variable to "pause" and when my function that was processing all the data woke up, it checked if the "pause" var was true. If it was then it paused and slept, woke up and checked again.